# White rectangle artifact when un-minimizing frameless window in qt5

Tags: python, pyside2

I created a basic qt5 application with Pyside2, and when un-minimizing the window, there is a white rectangular artifact in the top left corner.

It also appears to be related to `self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)` as when I remove that line and try the minimize button with the window titlebar still there it doesn't have the issue.

White rectangle at top left corner + the actual app

[image]

I'm wondering if theres any solution to this.

```py
import os
from pathlib import Path
import sys

from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PySide2.QtCore import QFile, Qt
from PySide2.QtUiTools import QUiLoader


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        self.window = None
        self.load_ui()

        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.dragging = False
        self.drag_pos = None

    def load_ui(self):
        loader = QUiLoader()
        path = os.fspath(Path(__file__).resolve().parent / "form.ui")
        ui_file = QFile(path)
        ui_file.open(QFile.ReadOnly)
        self.window = loader.load(ui_file, self)
        ui_file.close()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        pos = event.globalPos() - self.pos()
        if not pos.y() > 45:
            self.dragging = True
            self.drag_pos = event.globalPos() - self.pos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.dragging:
            self.move(event.globalPos() - self.drag_pos)
            event.accept()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.dragging = False


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    MainWindow = Window()

    MainWindow.window.closeButton.clicked.connect(lambda: app.quit())
    MainWindow.window.minimizeButton.clicked.connect(lambda: MainWindow.setWindowState(Qt.WindowMinimized))

    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And also the ui file https://pastebin.com/DAuYDwwE

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: @SynthesisDrive that is *not* reproducible. Where is the ui file it refers to?